# Can someone explain some simple python concepts to me?

Tags: python

I've been working through "Learn Python the Hard Way" and so far it's going pretty well, but I have a couple of questions:

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apricots']
change = [1, 'pennies', 2, 'dimes', 3, 'quarters']

# this first kind of for-loop goes through a list
for number in the_count:
    print "This is count %d" % number

# same as above
for fruit in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % fruit

# also we can go through mixed lists too
# notice we have to use %r since we don't know what's in it
for i in change:
    print "I got %r" % i
```

In these for loops, respectively, does it matter what the words "number", "fruit" and "i" are? It feels like everything in python needs to be defined but we never really "defined" number if that makes sense. I'm not exactly sure how to word this question correctly =/

Comment: No it doesn't. It just puts what ever you call it in scope of that loop.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't matter what you use for those names. You can pick any name you wish for these identifiers, as long as they are valid python identifiers.

Name them `foo`, `bar`, `vladiwostok`, whatever. It *is* a good idea to pick a name that is a little more descriptive of course, so `fruit` or `number` are great names in the context that they are used.

In any case, all of te following are equivalent:

```
for foo in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % foo

for bar in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % bar

for vladivostok in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % vladivostok
```

Comment: `for vladiwostok in fruits` has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Also, in fact, they don't have to be plain identifiers. Any assignable value will do: `for foo.bar in fruits`

Comment: @nneonneo: I considered going into target lists, but given the context of the lessons the OP is following now, reckoned that a little too deep still.

Answer (score 1):

The actual word you use to call these variables is not important.  Obviously if you called them something else, you would have to use the new name to refer to them.

ie) you couldn't have

```
for bla in the_count:
    print "This is the count &d" %number
```

because you havn't defined what number is

Python is different from many other languages in the fact that it is very weakly typed.
you don't need to explicetly say anywhere what the type of a variable is.

In C/C++ an integer variable would be defined as such

```
int i;
i=24;
```

In Python, to define a variable, it is sufficient to just set it to some value.  For example,

```
i=24
```

will implicitly define i to be an integer.

likewise, the line

```
for number in the_count:
```

will implicetly define number to be a variable of the same type as the_count.

However, a variable's type can change.  It can switch any number of times just by assigning value of a different type to the variable.

ie.

```
i=12        #i is an integer
i="bla"     #i has changed to a string
i=true      #i has changeed to a bool
```

Comment: Note: Python has dynamic yet **strong** type system since type is very defined for each variable at every moment of time.

Answer (score 0):

`for <name> in <value>:` is semantically equivalent to a loop like

```
__iter = iter(<value>)
while 1:
    try:
        <name> = __iter.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    <block>
```

Therefore, you can put anything you want for `<name>` so long as it would normally fit on the left-hand side of an assignment. Normally, this is a plain identifier, but you can use attributes too:

```
class Namespace: pass
foo = Namespace()

for foo.bar in range(10):
    print foo.bar

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for l[0] in range(10):
    print l
```

Answer (score 0):

As other fellas said before, it does not matter because Python is smart enough and is able to understand *under the hood* what is the exact type of the object that is been referencing. You just have to be worried about if the name of the variable is not weird and/or meaningless :)

Also, you said these sentence:

> In these for loops, respectively, does it matter what the words
>   "number", "fruit" and "i" are? It feels like everything in python
>   needs to be defined but we never really "defined" number if that makes
>   sense. I'm not exactly sure how to word this question correctly =/

The good point in Python is that you don't have to code anything based on types, but in objects. What I mean is that you should not work with codes like this sample:

```
def hello(arg):
   if type(arg) is "str":
       // do something
   elif type(arg) is "list":
       // do another thing
```

You must be the less restrictive possible in that way, because in Python a lot of functions implements polymorphism and they work well accepting different types as passed in parameters. This makes a lot easier to create programs, because the language is strongly typed, but a well-coded function for a specific problem could be able to work with ints, floats and strings.